# Not received replication information orphaned domain controller win 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain, replication

All 3 our domain controllers in 3 different sites keep generating the same active directory error.

> This directory server has not recently received replication information from a number of directory servers.  The count of directory servers is shown, divided into the following intervals.

I have ran the command:

```
repadmin /showvector /latency <partition-dn>
```

as suggested to find the faulty servers.

This generates the following output

```
80bff6d6-bec5-4491-8cc6-f7327f1f92e5 @ USN    878172 @ Time 2009-11-04 09:30:19
bd337b26-a818-4567-b96f-90565a092c47 @ USN     20709 @ Time 2009-11-18 11:55:46
05671519-2239-42b5-96a2-04638d26fc3b @ USN   1601121 @ Time 2014-09-26 15:51:44
hbov\LostAndFoundConfig              @ USN     12495 @ Time 2014-09-30 12:56:23
3 correct servers listed here aswell
```

As you can see there are 3 old guid listed. I have tried to delete them with the ntdsutil -> metadata cleanup utility but the servers aint listed in any site. THerefore I cannot delete them... They are also not listed in active directory users & computers and not listed in AD sites & services. I canot find any dns records and I have no clue what the names of these servers was.

Can someone help me delete these orphaned servers from our domain please...

Comment: ADSIEdit is the tool, make backups first.  
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555846

Comment: I have tried to find these guid in adsiEdit but no luck!